# TFVC checkin best practice

Tags: c#, tfs, tfvc

Many people told me that the best practice of `checking in` my code on `TFVC` is `getting latest` before.

I don't know why I think that TFS smart enough and there is no difference between `getlatest` then `checkin` or `getlatest` after `checkin`

Comment: because it's better to resolve possible conflicts by your self rather than to leave this job for someone else

Comment: as @simoco said, it is better to first retrieve all modifications, check that everything is fine/compile/pass tests before commit anything.

Keep in mind that your work may be ok, but not compatible with distant modifications.

Comment: You may be able to automatically merge, but does that mean that all tests are passing? That the code still compiles?No. So you do a get-latest, you perform a build, you run the tests and you check in.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion when working with TFVC in TFS, the process should be:

1. You get latest
2. You write your tests
3. You make them pass
4. You get latest including conflicts and resolve all conflicts
5. You run your tests
6. If they fail you fix and go back to 4
7. When they pass and after doing a get latest you checkin

(this process is the same for all server-based source control systems)

If you do not do this then you are not writing your code on the latest codebase so while tfvc can merge, if something has happened like a method being changed or removed, the merge won't help.

Be a good citizen and get latest before you checkin - ideally you should have a CI build which checks this and if you do you will often break the build which is bad for everyone.

Edited: I have added that when you checkout you also get all conflicts, otherwise if you have done something like added a file the project won't be downloaded when you do a get latest, this is pretty important actually with TFS.

Answer (score 2):

I would share some of my opinions when working with TFS:

It's smart, it helps to perform auto-merge many times (if my code is not conflict with others). Otherwise, you can see all conflicted files and do merge yourself file by file or you can decide to take server version / local version.

If not doing get latest, you may need to perform a second shoot, example:
- You add some files to a project Business.csproj
- Your colleage also added some files to that project. TFS merges the file and requires Visual Stiduo to reload the project.

Let's imaging we often review all changes, run tests... before checking in. There are 40 files, on both cases confliction or reload project, a second check needs to be done...